# Combinations with options based on another option

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm totally lost for the combination when it comes to dependency.

Example: You have three choices of tie:  polka-dot, striped, and solid-color. The rest of your wardrobe consists of shirts and pants from 6 different brands.  For each brand, you have 2 different colors of shirts. You have 10 pants, but only that know you have at least one of each brand.

How many different outfits could be made if you have to pick a tie, shirt and pants, but the shirt and pants must be from the same brand.

I'm confused about the relation between the pants and shirt as they have to be the same brand and how that changes the numbers.

Comment: You have 3 choices of tie and 6 choices of brand. Once you have picked a brand, you have 2 choices of shirt color. Assuming that pants of the same brand are identical, by picking the brand you have already picked the pants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick a shirt, you have to do case analysis on the distribution of trousers between brands. Likewise if you pick a brand. But if you pick the trousers first, that fixes the brand, and you know how many dependent options of shirt there are.

The big problem with this question is that it's ambiguous: I assume that it wouldn't say how many trousers you have unless that mattered, but someone else in the comments assumed that trousers from the same brand are indistinguishable.